# calling getMap() inside nested mapfragment gives nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-nested-fragment, mapfragment

I have a mapfragment inside a custom fragment, by calling it like in the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24139902/how-to-use-mapfragment-in-custom-fragment-correctly/24140489#24140489)

Unfortunatly there's a NullPointerException, if I call the getMap()-Method (see attached code). Has anybody an idea why? Thanks for your help!

```
private void initializeMap() {
    initializeMapFragment();

    try {
        // show current location
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        // adding marker
        addDestinationMarker();

        // zoom to current location
        Location myLocation = map.getMyLocation();
        if (myLocation != null) {
            LatLng currentPosition = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(currentPosition).zoom(12).build();
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(currentPosition));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void initializeMapFragment() {
    MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if (fm.findFragmentByTag("my_map_fragment") == null) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.map_container, mapFragment, "my_map_fragment").commit();
    }
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
}
```

EDIT //

The xml of the HomeFragment looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1">

<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|left|right|center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_lines"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/alarmButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/BlueButtonStyle"
            android:text="@string/btn_alarm"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the xml for your fragment

Comment: I'v added it to the original post.

Comment: I think you need to wait for the `Fragment` `View` inflate (and map initialization) in order to retrieve the `GoogleMap` instance. So i suggest you to use an `Listener` to be called after `onViewCreated`.

Comment: Okay, I don't understand how I can achieve this. Can you provide some code? Thanks!